# How to find the maximum value and the argument of a function of three variables y dividing into grids?

Tags: functions

I am dealing with a non-linear function of three variables, namely R0k, R1 and alpha. To find its maximum value, I divided the three variables into grids and maximized the function by plotting the maximum value of the function on the grid of alpha, on all the grid points of the two variables. Now I want the value of all those alpha at which the function attained its maximum value. How do I find it?
Here is my code:

```
tbl = Table[
  Flatten[{R0k, R1, 
    Max[Table[bTransp61[(i - 1) Pi 45/180/78]^2, {i, 0, 79}]]}], 
   {R1, 0, 21.43, .1}, {R0k, 2*(R1/R1el)^2*R0kel - R0kel, 19.71, .1}]
tbl >> "datafile.nb"
Export["tbl.dat", tbl]
tbl2 = Table[Flatten[tbl, 1], {1}]
ListPlot3D[tbl2, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0004}]
```

Comment: Did you try `FindMaximum`?

Comment: You code is not helpful when it's not possible to execute it.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not fully clear to me, but I think `Position` might be what you're looking for. You can use it to find elements in a list that match a certain criterion. In this case  being equal to the maximum value(s) of the list.

```
m = RandomInteger[20, {10, 10}]; (* generate a random array *)

posMax = Position[m, Max[m]]; (* Find the positions of the maximum value(s) *)

Grid[m, Background -> {None, None, (# -> Pink) & /@ posMax}] (* Display results *)
```

[image]

`Position` works on ragged lists too:

```
m = Table[RandomInteger[10], {i, 10}, {j, i}];
posMax = Position[m, Max[m]];
Grid[m, Background -> {None, None, (# -> Pink) & /@ posMax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is useful in your case as one of the `Table` boundaries seems to depend on the other.

It works in 3D and any other number of dimensions too.

```
m = RandomInteger[20, {4, 4, 4}];
posMax = Position[m, Max[m]];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.1], {Sphere[#, 0.3] & /@ posMax}}, 
             MapIndexed[Text[#1, #2] &, m, {3}]}]
```

[image]

So, if you hadn't used the `Max` function in the first line of your code `Position` would be able to find the max values directly. You now first have to find the positions of the maximum values in 2D and then search for the alpha value that created them.

Please note that Mathematica has quite a few function for finding maximum values. You might want to start reading [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MinimizationAndMaximization.html).

Comment: I'm getting dizzy...